# Using base64_encode safely

Tags: php, encoding, base64, password-hash

I´m using base64 to encode a string. So currently it can have "/+=" but that is a problem, because for example I´m uploading a file with encoding a part of the filename with base64_encode and that could have a "/" inside and break the process.
So I searched a bit and found this functions instead of using base64_encode

```
function base64_url_encode($input)
{
return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input)
{
return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```

I have two questions to this:

- The encoding function replaces "+" for "-", but "-" remains "-". So the decode function will replace "-" with "+". But it could also be that it should remain "-". So is this function valid? For me it sounds like a function with character problems.
- I am using my private encrypt function to encrypt passwords. This functions uses base64_encode. So would it make problems to use the function above instead? Could problems arise if the encrypted password contains "/" currently?

If this functions are bad, what would be the alternative?

Sorry for asking this, but I really would not ask if it would be trivial for me

Comment: `-` is not a valid base64 character.

Comment: Also, instead of doing a strtr on this, you should really just do a urlencode which will change the characters to their `%` entities. On the next page, php will automatically url_decode and the string in the $_GET array will just be the valid base64 string. urlencode is for encoding strings in urls where the string might contain valid url characters.

Comment: Sorry but I need a not urlencoded string, so this is not a solution for me. @JonathanKuhn you said "-" is not a valid character. What should the function use instead? Can someone reply to my questions?

Comment: Your function can change whatever characters you want. My point is that the base64_encode php function will never return `-` as that is not a valid character in base64. As for your second question, I really hope you aren't actually using your own "private encrypt function". When it comes to passwords, "encryption" shouldn't even be in the same sentence. Unless you are mistaking hashing for encryption. And even then, don't roll your own.